# Quelle est la signification de l'expression "une fille indigne" ? Comment l'utilise-t-on au quotidien ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Hier, mon amie m’a demandé « Est-ce que tu sais traduire “une fille indigne” en anglais ? »  Et puis, on a parlé de son utilisation dans les conversations quotidiennes.

Mais, franchement, je ne la comprends pas. Peut-être est-elle liée à l'histoire de la bande dessinée française ou quelque chose comme ça ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il y a trois questions.

> "Qu'est-ce que cela veut dire ?"

Indigne veut dire proprement: qui n'est pas digne de, qui ne mérite pas qqch qui lui est attribué.

Appliqué à une [personne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/indigne) –une fille, un époux, un père, un fils indigne(s)– il est sous-entendu que la qualité qui n'est pas méritée est la position, le titre, de la personne.

Autrement dit "une fille indigne" est quelqu'un qui ne mérite pas d'être la fille de ses parents. C'est la définition non connotée.

Au figuré, il faudrait le contexte pour pouvoir préciser les nuances avec lesquelles ce terme est utilisé.

Il peut y avoir une connotation de rébellion sociale (si on entend fille comme dans les fils/filles d'un pays), une connotation un peu sexuelle (si fille est utilisée dans le sens "la fille avec qui je sors") etc.

Cela peut varier suivant le sens de fille ici ou de la figure parentale qui est sous-entendue dans cette phrase.

> "Comment utilise-t-on le terme au quotidien ?"

C'est une expression très peu utilisée à l'oral et certainement pas "au quotidien" dans les deux pays francophones où j'ai vécu (France, Canada). Plutôt courante à l'écrit, même si l'expression de base "fils indigne" est évidemment beaucoup plus courante dû à son utilisation dans la bible.

"How to translate it in English ?"

Oxford gives "bad" or "unworthy" depending of the context. Really the concept of "the bad son" taken from the Bible became the normal and most usual term for this. It's the simplest and most accurate translation.

> *une fille indigne* → She's a bad daughter;
>
> *une conduite indigne d'un officier* → a conduct unworthy of an
>   officer

For reference you can read the description of this book [Bad daughter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935536168) by Sarah Gorham. It uses pretty much all the connotations of the term:

> "Bad Daughter explores misbehavior—its risky pleasures and often tragic
>   consequences—through poems about “bad” daughters, sisters, and their
>   mothers. What happens to the sister who obeys? What if a daughter
>   refuses her inheritance? Can she? What sanctuary and what limits do
>   worship and domesticity provide? Gorham adopts several lyric
>   forms—‘morality tales,’ ironic prayers, scaled-down sonnets, sharp
>   meditations on concepts such as envy, detachment, and immortality—to
>   show that the self as forged by generations of women and girls is both
>   subversive and enduring."

Answer (score 3):

Les racines de l'indignité des filles commencent par la perte de la virginité hors mariage dans les sociétés patriarcales, se développent dans une conduite dévergondée ou par un mariage sans l'accord parental et finissent par plonger dans des comportements vénaux.

> Une *fille indigne* salit l'honneur de sa famille qui la rejette ; dans certaines traditions sa mort lave l'honneur de la famille.

Il y a donc un jugement social sur l'indignité d'une fille qui se libère du joug familial, des pressions sociales et assume sa liberté.

L'indignité des hommes n'est pas liée à leur sexualité, ni à l'emprise familiale, mais à leur capacité à défendre l'honneur de la famille, d'assurer leur rôle social sans mentir ni trahir, de tenir leur rang.

Être jugée *fille indigne* indique que l'on considère comme mineure la femme soumise à l'homme.

Pour les sociétés égalitaires, assumer être *fille indigne* peut signifier être une *femme libérée* qui a lutté pour sa liberté, sa féminité, sa dignité.

Il y a donc un contexte à prendre en compte pour une traduction fidèle.

Comment: Fille indigne/bad daughter semblent venir toutes deux de l'expression biblique le fils indigne/the bad son. Les deux termes recouvrent presque exactement les mêmes connotations parce qu'ils font référence au même fond commun culturel. La description de ce livre, Bad daughter, (http://www.amazon.com/Bad-Daughter-Sarah-Gorham/dp/1935536168¼ )résume bien les diverses connotation du terme.

Comment: @JoBedard seulement le sort du *fils indigne* et celui ne la *fille indigne* ne se ressemblent pas : d'un coté mis au ban de la famille, de la société ou exclus du groupe mais capable de circuler sur d'autres terres, de l'autre répudiée, faite nonne voire lapidée.

Comment: Ce qui est "normal" dans une société patriarcale ou les femmes sont un bien censé rester enfermé d'une façon ou d'une autre (mariage, maison, couvent).